# Define all the attributes of a table from a database

Tags: php, database, web-services, wampserver

I'm developing a web service with one parameter which is the name of a table. Is there any method to determine all the attributes of my table while fetching the request.

```
 <?php
 // Call Address  URL: url: http://localhost/test1/new.php?tab=Request_Table -> GET
 $response = array(); //array for JSON response
 if(isset($_GET["tab"])){ //check for post data
 $tab = $_GET['tab'];
 $element = array();
 if(!empty($tab)){
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM '$tab'");
 if(!empty($result)) { //check for empty result
 while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ // Fetching results
 extract($data);
 $element["attribute1"] = $data["attribute1"];
 $element["attribute2"] = $data["attribute2"];
 } 
 $response = array("success" => 1, "element" => $element);
 echo json_encode($response); // echoing JSON response
 }else{ //not element found
 $response["success"] = 0;
 $response["message"] = "No element found";
 echo json_encode($response);
  }
  }else { //not element found
  $response["success"] = 0;
  $response["message"] = "No element found";
  echo json_encode($response);
  }
  }else{ // required field is missing
  $response["success"] = 0;
  $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";
  }
  ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
// Call Address  URL: url: http://localhost/test1/new.php?tab=Request_Table -> GET
$response = array(); //array for JSON response
if(isset($_GET["tab"])){ //check for post data
    $tab = $_GET['tab'];
    $element = array();
    if(!empty($tab)){
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tab");
        if(!empty($result)) { //check for empty result
            $data = array();
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ // Fetching results
                $data[] = $row;
            }
            $response = array("success" => 1, "element" => $data);
        }else{ //not element found
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "No element found";
        }
    }else { //not element found
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "No valid table name";
    }
}else{ // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";
}
echo json_encode($response); // echoing JSON response
?>
```

Comment: It it is the correct answer of your question, then please accept it.